# change to numeric a specific column for multiple text files in a directory using R

Tags: r

I have a list of text files and for each file there are 6 columns. I want to classify the sixth column as numeric. How should I modify the code below? Would a `for` loop help instead?

```
num_ea <- lapply(list.files(), FUN = function(x) {
num_trait <- as.numeric(x$6, header = T))
return(num_trait)
})
```

Comment: You should first read the datasets i..e. `lapply(list.files(), function(x) {dat <- read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); dat$num_trait <- as.numeric(dat[[6]])})`

Comment: Note that `return(=num_trait)` is not valid R syntax.

Comment: (=... was a typo error. edited, thanks.